# Dynamic Nested Routes nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to create the following structure in nuxt

`image/:slug`: User can see an image view

`image/:slug/annotation/:comment-id`: user can see the image on the background but also a pop up shows up with the comment

I have the following folder structure:

```
image
|
| _slug
|  annotation
|    _id.vue
|  index.vue
```

On `index.vue`:

```
<template>
  <section>
    <image-annotation
      :image="activeImage"
      :annotations="activeImageAnnotations"
    />

    <v-divider />
    <title-row />

    <nuxt-child />
  </section>
</template>
```

I was reading the [docs](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing#dynamic-nested-routes) but I'm not being able to achieve my final goal

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to simply go up one level:

```
image
|
|  _slug
|    annotation
|      _id.vue
|  _slug.vue
```